# VBA UserForm: Filter Name with square Bracket

Tags: vba, filter, userform, brackets, square-bracket

I have problem when searching with square bracket to seach name: for example Peter[Jones] (combobox1). It coundn't find that name?

How to fix this problem? Anyone can help or suggest

```
Dim a, LngIndex As Long
Dim ytCrit, mtCrit, dtCrit As Long
Dim yuCrit, muCrit, duCrit As Long
Dim sCrit As String
Dim tCrit, uCrit As Date
Dim vCrit, wCrit As Long
Dim tngSource As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next

Set tngSource = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:K" & LastRow)

sCrit = "*" & UCase(ComboBox1) & "*"
With ListBox1
    For a = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Not UCase(.List(a, 1)) Like sCrit Then
            .RemoveItem a
        End If
    Next a
End With
```

Comment: If you use `Like`, you must escape characters in the pattern that are [special for `Like`](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Like-Operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931?CorrelationId=08053167-2ac6-4273-ac02-19e5db5b9247&ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA). In your particular case, just use `InStr`.

Answer (score 0):

> ...searching with square bracket to seach name: for example Peter[Jones]

The square brackets `[` and `]` of the `Like` operator contains a *list of characters* to search for in the match. It does not mean a name like "[Jones]" is optional.

So `s Like "[Jones]"` will match anything containing a J, an o an n an e or an s.

As user  GSerg writes, use the `InStr` function to search a string for a substring. The search will be case sensitive.